# Looping over XML nodes in SQL

Tags: sql, xml

I want to loop over all my xml nodes using SQL, and add an attribute on each node.

For example, given the input:

```
<Customer> 
    <FirstName>tom</FirstName>
    <LastName>hamel</LastName>
</Customer>
```

I want to add an `editTime` attribute to the `FirstName` and `LastName` nodes, resulting in:

```
<Customer>
    <FirstName editTime='2011-10-25 10:13:13.787'>tom</FirstName>
    <LastName editTime='2011-10-25 10:13:13.787'>hamel</LastName>
</Customer>
```

Can somebody give me a hint as to how to do this in SQL?

Comment: Among the absolute minimum data required to think about this question are 1) the language you're working in, 2) how you have your XML stored and 3) how your question relates to SQL.

Comment: Why don't you deserialize it with xml and serialize it again with the proper attributes?

Comment: How does this tie in with SQL? All I'm seeing is XML. If you want to update an XML document within an SQL statement, first find out if the DBMS you're using has an XML datatype. If not, get it as text, send it through an XSLT sheet or something and update the value with another statement.

Comment: Is your data stored as xml or do you want to output xml based on your data in a certain format?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that many SQL databases do support XML operations. Microsoft SQL Server certainly does. @Jason, could you please edit your question to tell us what SQL database you're using?

Answer (score 2):

Loops are achieved in SQL with [cursors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29), ***however***:

- SQL is declarative - hence looping should be a last resource
- You can access XML variables with better ways, see [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226440%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

So be totally sure you're going down the correct route first, as I highly doubt it.